# ArcGIS Modelbuilder model clogs up memory?

Tags: arcmap, performance, memory, model

I have a model in which a zonal histogram is computed of each line in a feature class, showing the amount of cells each line intersects in a raster file. After this, this column is joined to a table that has values of the first line in it.

[image: This is the model]

This works. The problem is, that [as can be read here,](https://community.esri.com/thread/67006) intermediate results are stored on the RAM (if I understand correctly). In my case, the first ~100 iterations are very fast (<0.1 seconds). However, after that it becomes increasingly slow, and since I have 50k lines in total, I need some way to speed this up.

What is the easiest way of running this model elsewhere, where it does not fill up the RAM?

Comment: you could add delete tool(s) to delete the temp data on every iteration

Comment: also remove your join at the end before the run happens again